# Load huge txt file for winform quickly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am going to make a sinhala english dictionary. SO i have a file that contains sinhala meaning for every english word. So i thought to load it while form is loading. So i added following command to get all file content to a string variable. SO i used following command in FormLoad method,

```
private string DictionaryWords = "";

private string ss = null;

...

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#AFC3E0");

    string fileName = @"SI-utf8.Txt";

    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        while ((ss = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            DictionaryWords += ss;
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately that txt file has 130000+ line and it size it more than 5MB. SO my winform not loading.

see the image

[image]

I need to load this faster for winform to use REGEX form getting right meaning for every english word..
Could anybody tell me a method to do this. I tried everything.

Load this huge file to my project within 15 more less and need to use Regex for finding each english words..

Comment: What does "not loading" mean?

Comment: What is `DictionaryWords`, please? `DictionaryWords += ss;` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Yet another possibility is to start *async Task* on `Form1_Load`, then whenever you want to obtain the dictionary you can `await` the previously ran task

Comment: What is the expected *regular expression* then? Please, note, that combining all the words into a single regex is a bad idea.

Comment: From the looks of it "DictionaryWords" is a string? If it is, I highly recommend changing it to an actual dictionary. Strings are immutable in c#, this means that every time you add something to a string, a new string will be created. You are essentially reading 130k strings, and then for every string, you diplicate the current string. The more, the slower it gets. TL;DR: Change to dictionary or List<string>

Comment: [edit] the question and include the definition for `DictionaryWords`. I suspect the issue here isn't the loading of the text file, which isn't that big, but the processing of the contents that is the problem here.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko dictionarywords means string variable which is store content of txt file

Comment: @Ryan Gabriel: so we know the culprit (`DictionaryWords += ss`) let's get rid of him: please, see my edit. Please, not that the felon can have an assistent which can be a *regular expression*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are too little code to analyze. I suspect that

```
DictionaryWords += ss;
```

is the felon: appending string `130000` times which means *re-creating* quite long string *over and over again* can well put the system on the knees, but I have not rigorous proof (I've asked about `DictionaryWords` in the comment). Another possible candidate to be blamed is the unknown for me your *regular expression*.

That's why let me try to solve the problem from scratch.

- We a have a (long) dictionary in `SI-utf8.Txt`.
- We should load the dictionary without freezing the UI.
- We should use the dictionary loaded to translate the English texts.

I have got something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

...

// Loading dictionary (async, since dictionary can be quite long)
// static: we want just one dictionary for all the instances
private static readonly Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>> s_Dictionary = 
  Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>>.Run(() => {
    char[] delimiters = { ' ', '\t' };

    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> result = File
      .ReadLines(@"SI-utf8.Txt")
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
      .Select(line => line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      .Where(items => items.Length == 2)
      .ToDictionary(items => items[0], 
                    items => items[1], 
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    return result;
  });
```

Then we need a translation part:

```
// Let it be the simplest regex: English letters and apostrophes;
// you can improve it if you like
private static readonly Regex s_EnglishWords = new Regex("[A-Za-z']+");

// Tanslation is async, since we have to wait for dictionary to be loaded
private static async Task<string> Translate(string englishText) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(englishText))
    return englishText;

  var dictionary = await s_Dictionary;

  return s_EnglishWords.Replace(englishText,
    match => dictionary.TryGetValue(match.Value, out var translation) 
      ? translation   // if we know the translation
      : match.Value); // if we don't know the translation
}
```

Usage:

```
// Note, that button event should be async as well
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TranslationTextBox.Text = await Translate(OriginalTextBox.Text);
}
```

**Edit:** So, `DictionaryWords` is a `string` and thus

```
DictionaryWords += ss;
```

is a *felon*. Please, don't append `string` in a (deep) loop: each append *re-creates* the string which is slow. If you insist on the looping, use `StringBuilder`:

```
// Let's pre-allocate a buffer for 6 million chars
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(6 * 1024 * 1024);

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    while ((ss = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.Append(ss);
    }
}

DictionaryWords = sb.ToString();
```

Or, why should you loop at all? Let .net do the work for you:

```
DictionaryWords = File.ReadAllText(@"SI-utf8.Txt");
```

**Edit 2:** If actual file size is not *that huge* (it is `DictionaryWords += ss;` *alone* who spoils the fun) you can stick to a simple synchronous solution:

```
private static readonly Regex s_EnglishWords = new Regex("[A-Za-z']+");

private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> s_Dictionary = File
  .ReadLines(@"SI-utf8.Txt")
  .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .Where(items => items.Length == 2)
  .ToDictionary(items => items[0], 
                items => items[1], 
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

private static string Translate(string englishText) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(englishText))
    return englishText;

  return s_EnglishWords.Replace(englishText,
    match => s_Dictionary.TryGetValue(match.Value, out var translation) 
      ? translation 
      : match.Value);
}
```

An then the usage is quite simple:

```
// Note, that button event should be async as well
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TranslationTextBox.Text = Translate(OriginalTextBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct solution here. For simplicity's sake can you provide a non-async version of this, assuming the actual reading of the text file is fast enough for the user not to notice really.

Comment: wow... Mr Dmitry Bychenko.. Sir you saved my time ,, Thanks a lot. your method is working.